# NumberFormate Exception

Tags: java

Given a non-negative number represented as an array of digits,

add 1 to the number ( increment the number represented by the digits ).

The digits are stored such that the most significant digit is at the head of the list.

Example:

If the vector has [1, 2, 3]

the returned vector should be [1, 2, 4}

```
    List<Integer> list=new ArrayList<Integer>();
    
    list.add(1);
    list.add(1);
    list.add(1);
    list.add(3);
    list.add(2);
    list.add(1);
    list.add(1);
    list.add(2);
    list.add(5);
    list.add(9);
    list.add(6);
    list.add(5);
    String str=new String("");
    for(int i=0;i<list.size();i++)
    {
        str=str+list.get(i);
    }
    //System.out.println(str);
    int value=Integer.parseInt(str);
    value=value+1;
    //System.out.println(value);
    char[] ch=Integer.toString(value).toCharArray();
    for(int i=0;i<ch.length;i++)
    {
        result.add(Character.getNumericValue(ch[i]));
    }
    System.out.println(result);
```

---

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "111321125965"
at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)
at com.problemsolving.AddOneArray.main(AddOneArray.java:28)
```

---

i don't know why
exception is occurring??

Comment: Integers can't be that big, but `long` values can.

Comment: Max value for `int` is `2147483647` which is lower than `111321125965`

Comment: If your number can exceed the max value of `long` data type, then try to apply logic by iterating over `string` starting from the end by converting a single character to `int` and then increment that and check for borrow, if there is borrow, then add to previous number and so on.

Comment: what if elements in list are in millions or billions?

Comment: You misunderstood the purpose of this excercise completely. The manipulation should be done with the list of digits without first converting it to a numeric type. Hint: how would you do the increment with paper and pencil?

Comment: okk i got it....

Answer (score 0):

Assign the parsed String to a **long**.

Replace this: `int value=Integer.parseInt(str);`

With this: `long value=Long.parseLong(str);`

Answer (score 0):

I think it's occurring because `111321125965` is too large for an integer. Integers are represented by 4 bytes, or 32 bits, one of which is for the sign - which means that an `int` maxes out at `2^31 - 1`. Yours is over `2^36`.

The `long` primitive (and its wrapper class `Long`) support 64 bytes, which lets the number max out at `2^63 - 1`. If you substitute those for your `int`s and `Integer`s respectively, then you should no longer see this error.

If you need *even bigger* numbers, you'll need to use the [`BigInteger`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html) class, which can handle arbitrarily large integers, but no longer maps directly to a primitive like `Integer` and `Long`, so you need to be more careful/deliberate in using it.

Answer (score 0):

It is occurring because you are over the max integer (Integer.MAX_VALUE) value , which should be 2,147,483,647.